# how to suspend a thread for 1 ms?

Tags: c#

I need prety simple thing

```
while (true) {
    DoJob();
    // wait 1 ms
}
```

Should I just use `Thread.Sleep(1)`?
I'm not sure about using `Timer` because it seems overhead of `Timer` itself is a little bit more than 1 ms.

**Update**: I need this delay to be sure that I received the most recent information from network, it's trading software. I need to do something and then I have to wait 1 ms to see what happens. I can wait 1.5 ms, but not 3 ms, that would be too much. It's ok to wait rarely 5 or 10 ms, but in general it should be ~1 ms

Comment: Thread.Sleep will probably cause a longer delay than 1 ms, more likely something in the tens of ms. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/facc2b57-9a27-4049-bb32-ef093fbf4c29  Why do you need to wait for 1ms? How precise does it have to be?

Comment: Depends on the context, but Thread.Sleep would do it.

Comment: @AndreLoker because I need this delay to be sure that I received the most recent information from network, it's trading software. I need to do something and then I have to wait 1 ms to see what happens. I can wait 1.5 ms, but not 3 ms, that would be too much. It's ok to wait `rarely` 5 or 10 ms, but in general it should be ~1 ms.

Comment: What happens to your logic when the OS swaps out your thread for a 1+ timeslices? Windows is not a real-time OS.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I just earn less money in worst case. It's ok to have such artifacts sometimes, but in average i want 1 ms delay.

Comment: even in average I don't need `exact` 1 ms. it's ok to have something between `0.3` and `2`

Comment: If you are getting information over a network, you will find delays of considerably more than 1ms happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit -- corrected "most resolution you will get from sleep to about 20 ms, instead of 100 ms**

About the most resolution that you will get out of sleep is 100 milliseconds, even if you pass Sleep(1).

For what it's worth, a timer may be more efficient for this -- especially if you have more than 1 thread sleeping (System.Threading.Timer will will use as few threads as it needs to if you allocate multiple timers, they will share a timing thread) (this from Joe Duffy's Concurrent Programming book)

But more importantly, what are you trying to do?  If you are polling -- need to wait for something to happen, you may be able to use a more efficient means of doing it.  If you just need to fire off a task every so often, A timer is probably going to be your best bet.

If you are only want to stop for a millisecond, may I ask why?  Are you just trying to make sure that your thread yields to other processes?

Comment: @JMarsh I've added to comment above what i'm tring to do. The problem is that with `Timer(1)` tests showing too slow perfomance and with `while(true)` loop without delay tests show too fast perfomance...

Comment: `If you are polling -- need to wait for something to happen` actually it is, but currently it is not possible to achieve this other way than just sleeping...

Comment: The resolution is around 20ms, not 100ms.

Answer (score 2):

There may be an alternative way to do this.  Windows has a high resolution timer.  You can read about it here: ["How to: Use the high resolution timer"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964692%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

I don't think that this works like a regular timer -- it doesn't fire off events, you just use it to measure how much time has passed with high precision.  However, you could loop on it, and execute code when a Millisecond passes (you will be consuming CPU the whole time).  Also, I agree with Henk's comments that Windows is not a realtime O/S -- you never know when the O/S will suspend your thread.